# How to load wordpress environment without loading the template?

Tags: wp-load.php, wp-blog-header.php, outside-wordpress

Basically I want to use wordpress functions for example `wp_create_user()` or `wp_update_user()` outside of wordpress (outside of wordpress directory).

I tried with all the below code snippets to load the wordpress environment, I am able to use the functions correctly in both the cases but the problem is that this also loads the wordpress template which I do not want.

**First Method:**

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require ('../blog/wp-load.php');
?>
```

**Second Method:**

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require ('../blog/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

**Directory Structure:**

```
/blog
  |
  |_ Wordpress installed here
/admin
  |
  |_ admin.php (I want to use wp functions here)
```

Note: I am using **Writr theme** in my wordpress blog.

Comment: what is your filename and where it is located relative to your wordpress setup ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't know the reason how this worked but it did.

At first, I was loading the wp environment in the beginning of my file and it was loading the wp template(wp theme) which I didn't want.

But now I loaded the wp environment at the end of the file and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you place the file in the WP root directory, e.g. http://mysite.com/myscript.php

```
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '../blog/wp-load.php' );
if (function_exists('wp_create_user')) {
    echo "wp_create_user() found";
}
```

If you are in a different directory, just make sure you are loading wp-load.php from the proper location.

Comment: I have mentioned the directory structure in my question, you can give the answer accordingly.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes and to do such a thing you can use something like this :

```
// load only basics
if ( SHORTINIT ) return false;
```

EDIT: I've found this constant. If set WordPress initializes to a minimum

Comment: tried, not working. The wp theme is being loaded.

Comment: I've edited code.

Comment: still not working

Comment: I've edited code again ^^

Answer (score 0):

The functions.php of the theme was breaking the html of my other page.
That's what I did and solved my problem:

```
define('STYLESHEETPATH', '');
define('TEMPLATEPATH', '');
require_once(RAIZ_WORDPRESS."/wp-load.php");
```