# Load wordpress enviroment for external content?

Tags: plugins, functions

We have a couple of forms and landing pages that cannot be stored in our wordpress installation as posts/pages. For this reason they remain apart from our Wordpress installation in a folder though they share the menubar, stylesheet and other resources.

My question is whether there is a way to integrate some Wordpress functionalities to them so as to be able to use some plugin functions we need (we are using a plugin for localization that works amazingly but it would be trouble if we had to localize these pages differently).

Is there a way to make this pages part of the Wordpress installation while keeping the content in them?

Comment: Like this? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127248/how-to-load-wordpress-environment-without-loading-the-template

Comment: Or this? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/90241/21376 I am really a little unclear about your requirements.